# Using worksheet_calculate when the number of rows change

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of data in column x and y:

[image: image of data in column x and y]

I want to compare column x to y and send out a notification whenever x > 2y. This is the code for that: (P.S. this code runs perfectly).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

If Range("A2").Value <> PrevValb Then
  PrevValb = Range("A2").Value
  If Range("A2").Value > 2 * Range("B2").Value Then
    Dim result1 As VbMsgBoxResult
    result1 = MsgBox("A2 has exceeded range", vbOKCancel, "Range Exceeded")
    If result1 = vbCancel Then
      Stop
  End If
  End If
End If

If Range("A3").Value <> PrevValc Then
  PrevValc = Range("A3").Value
  If Range("A3").Value > 2 * Range("B3").Value Then
    Dim result2 As VbMsgBoxResult
    result2 = MsgBox("A3 has exceeded range", vbOKCancel, "Range Exceeded")
    If result2 = vbCancel Then
      Stop
    End If
  End If
End If

If Range("A4").Value <> PrevVald Then
  PrevVald = Range("A4").Value
  If Range("A4").Value > 2 * Range("B4").Value Then
    Dim result3 As VbMsgBoxResult
    result3 = MsgBox("A4 has exceeded range", vbOKCancel, "Range Exceeded")
    If result3 = vbCancel Then
      Stop
    End If
  End If
End If

If Range("A5").Value <> PrevVale Then
  PrevVale = Range("A5").Value
  If Range("A5").Value > 2 * Range("B5").Value Then
    Dim result4 As VbMsgBoxResult
    result4 = MsgBox("A5 has exceeded range", vbOKCancel, "Range Exceeded")
    If result4 = vbCancel Then
      Stop
    End If
  End If
End If

End Sub
```

BUT the number of rows change everyday and so do the cell values (A2, A3, A4, A5). I've created a NamedRange for all the values in column x and y. Is there a way to make the cell values dynamic? I would like to use a loop with integers wherein each integer refers to the row number and the loop continues until it reaches the last row. But I'm not sure how to combine that with this existing code.

Please let me know if you require any clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop your code since the last row like this :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim rangeName As String
rangeName = "NamedRange"

firstRowNamedRange = Range(rangeName).Row
lastRowNamedRange = Range(rangeName).Row + Range(rangeName).Rows.count


    For i = firstRowNamedRange To lastRowNamedRange Step 1

        If Range("A" & i).Value <> PrevValb Then
            PrevValb = Range("A" & i).Value
                If Range("A" & i).Value > 2 * Range("B2" & i).Value Then
                    Dim result1 As VbMsgBoxResult
                    result1 = MsgBox("A" & i & " has exceeded range", vbOKCancel, "Range Exceeded")
                    If result1 = vbCancel Then
                    Stop
                     End If
                End If
        End If


    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This works pretty well! Except I want it to stop checking after it reaches the last row of the NamedRange. I have cells below this NamedRange that don't need to be tested whether x>2y or not. Is this possible?

Comment: Try to cancel ' + 1' in the var lastrow_ws1 ans let me know :)

Comment: I'm still getting the notification when a cell outside the NamedRange is changed :/ 

Also, would this code allow me to insert rows above the NamedRange? Like would the "i = 2" change? 

Do you think it's possible to start at the first row of the NamedRange and end at the last row of the NamedRange? Because that would allow me to insert rows above and below w/o changing the code?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I also think you need to change : Range("B2" & i) to Range("B" & i) :)

Comment: Look at the edited code. I added first and last row in the loop from your NamedRange. Let met know if it's work

Comment: When I close & re-open the workbook, I'm getting a run-time error 13 (type mismatch) error - in the line:         If Range("A" & i) <> PrevValb Then

Comment: In ThisWorkbook, I have the code Private Sub Workbook_Open() PrevValb = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value End Sub - should I change this?

Comment: What is the purpose of the sub in thisworbook. You have range with 'i' var. But 'i' is not defined

Comment: That works perfectly! Do you know how to add multiple worksheet_calculate subs in one sheet?

Comment: Great ! glad to help you. Do not forget to vote and validate my answer

Comment: I don't now if it possible to add multiple sub calculate because is base on event. So I thnik that is not possible

Comment: Thanks so much! Just for reference, you can add multiple worksheet_calculate subs in one sheet just by copying the body of the code into the worksheet_calculate sub. (for e.g. Sub worksheet_calculate() macro code1, macro code2, macro code3 End Sub)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JC Guidicelli, this is the final code that works perfectly!

Sheet1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim rangeName As String
rangeName = "RangeOfValues"

firstRowNamedRange = Range(rangeName).Row
lastRowNamedRange = Range(rangeName).Row + Range(rangeName).Rows.Count - 1

For i = firstRowNamedRange To lastRowNamedRange Step 1

    If Range("A" & i).Value <> PrevValb Then
        PrevValb = Range("A" & i).Value
            If Range("A" & i).Value > 2 * Range("B" & i).Value Then
                Dim result As VbMsgBoxResult
                result = MsgBox("A" & i & " has exceeded range", vbOKCancel, "Range Exceeded")
                If result = vbCancel Then
                Stop
                End If
            End If
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Module:

```
Public PrevValb As Variant
```